# Problem with displaying individual filter in search form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have search form to list properties/ads through certain criteria (property Bid-Ask, Property Payment, Property Type, price, quadrature`). When I select all the criteria that there are, it shows all and correct results in the table. The problem is when I select one or two criteria, it should return all properties that have just those two criteria, but instead I get redirected to 404 not found page. Also, my URL, then works fine, it shows the right URL, just with 404. I have three tables.

```
properties (id, city, price, quadrature, property_type)
categories (id, category, priority)
category_property (id, property_id, category_id)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

**search.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
    <div>
        @if(isset($results))
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>Property Bid Ask</th>
                <th>Property Payment</th>
                <th>Property Type</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quadrature</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($results as $result)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $result->category[0]->category }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $result->category[1]->category }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $result->category[2]->category }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $result->city }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $result->price }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $result->quadrature }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        @endif

    </div>
    <form id="searchForm" method="GET" action="/search">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                <label>City</label>
                <input name="city" list="result" id="input" class="form-control">
                <datalist id="result"></datalist>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-6">
                <label>Price</label>
                <input type="number" name="min_price" class="form-control" placeholder="Min Price">
                <input type="number" name="max_price" class="form-control" placeholder="Max Price">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-6">
                <label>Quadrature</label>
                <input type="number" name="min_quadrature" class="form-control" placeholder="Min quadrature">
                <input type="number" name="max_quadrature" class="form-control" placeholder="Max quadrature">
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="mb-4">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 mb-6">
                <h5>Payment</h4>
                <div class="d-block my-3">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input id="ponuda" name="propertyBidAsk" value="ponuda" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="ponuda">Ponuda</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input id="potraznja" name="propertyBidAsk" value="potraznja" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="potraznja">Potraznja</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 mb-6">
                <h5>Property payment</h4>
                <div class="d-block my-3">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input id="kupovina" name="propertyPayment" value="kupovina" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="kupovina">Kupovina</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input id="izdavanje" name="propertyPayment" value="izdavanje" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="izdavanje">Izdavanje</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 mb-6">
                <h5>Property type</h4>
                <div class="d-block my-3 ">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input id="house" name="propertyType" value="house" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="house">House</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input id="flat" name="propertyType" value="flat" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="flat">Flat</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="mb-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Search</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        var onSubmitFunc = function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if( e.stopImmediatePropagation ){
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
            var propertyBidAsk = this["propertyBidAsk"].value.trim() || 0;
            var propertyPayment = this["propertyPayment"].value.trim() || 0;
            var propertyType = this["propertyType"].value.trim() || 0;
            var city = this['city'].value.trim() || 0;
            var min_price = this["min_price"].value.trim() || 0;
            var max_price = this["max_price"].value.trim() || 0;
            var price = min_price + "_" + max_price;
            var min_quadrature = this["min_quadrature"].value.trim() || 0;
            var max_quadrature = this["max_quadrature"].value.trim() || 0;
            var quadrature = min_quadrature + "_" + max_quadrature;
            url = propertyBidAsk.length === 0 ? '' : ( '/' + encodeURIComponent(propertyBidAsk) );
            url += propertyPayment.length === 0 ? '' : ( '/' +  encodeURIComponent(propertyPayment) );
            url += propertyType.length === 0 ? '' : ( '/' + encodeURIComponent(propertyType) );
            url += city.length === 0 ? '' : ( '/' + encodeURIComponent(city) );
            url += min_price.length === 0 ? '' : ( '/min_price' + "=" + encodeURIComponent(min_price) );
            url += max_price.length === 0 ? '' : ( '-max_price' + "=" + encodeURIComponent(max_price) );
            url += min_quadrature.length === 0 ? '' : ( '/min_quadrature' + "=" + encodeURIComponent(min_quadrature) );
            url += max_quadrature.length === 0 ? '' : ( '-max_quadrature' + "=" + encodeURIComponent(max_quadrature) );
            window.location.href = this.action + url;
        }

        document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            var srch = document.getElementById("searchForm");
            srch.addEventListener('submit', onSubmitFunc, false);
        }, false );

    </script>
</div>
```

**CategoryController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Property;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = \DB::table('properties');
        return view('categories.search', compact('data'));
    }

    public function search($propertyBidAsk, $propertyType, $propertyPayment, $city, $price, $quadrature, Request $request, Property $property)
    {

        $category = $property->category;

        $property_obj = Property::query();

        if (!empty($request->city)) {
            $property_obj->where('city', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->city . "%");
        }

        if (!empty($request->min_price) && !empty($request->max_price)) {
            $property_obj->whereBetween('price', [$min_price, $max_price]);
        }

        if (!empty($request->min_quadrature) && !empty($request->max_quadrature)) {
            $property_obj->whereBetween('quadrature', [$min_quadrature, $max_quadrature]);
        }

        $results =  $property_obj->get();
        dd($request->all());
        return view('categories.search', compact('category', 'results'));
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/search', 'CategoryController@index');
Route::get('/search/{propertyBidAsk}/{propertyPayment}/{propertyType}/
{city}/{price}/{quadrature}', 'CategoryController@search');
```

Comment: I think one of the reason is when the others is empty so your url will change and your route will not recognize it.

Comment: @JovenSalvador How should I change my code in order that to work?

Comment: did that solved the problem or not?

Comment: @JovenSalvador It helped, I get the idea, I just can't seem to put it right in code

Comment: just ask. maybe I can help more :)

Comment: @JovenSalvador I edited code. Added || 0 near var in javascipt tag. It is something similar to your idea. Now it doesn't return 404 page, but I am having trouble when I search (for example I have three ads in database with price 1000, 2000, 3000) min price 1000 max price 2000 it returns all three ads and it is supposed to return only two. And for all other filters same. Can you help?

Comment: did you already solved the problem? you need to use wherebetween in controller

Comment: @JovenSalvador I was unavailable last two days. I didn't solve the problem. How should exactly use wherebetween?

Comment: try this one `->whereBetween('price', [$min, $max]');`

Comment: @JovenSalvador It still returns all results and not those filtered.

Comment: does your request is not empty if you use `dd($request->all());`?

Comment: i updated my answer. Don't use `-` anymore use `?` also in max. that should do it

Comment: @JovenSalvador I tried with your answer and with wherebertween and it doesn't show any results, and with mine solution when I dd($request->all()); it returns empty array. I'm confused. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you update your code on your question?

Comment: and try to see if all of your var in javascript are not empty using `alert()`

Comment: @JovenSalvador I edited the code with this solution where it returns empty array when I dd(). and I tried alert and it returns var.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195781/discussion-between-jovs-and-gacho).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this. instead of using / you can use ?

```
url = propertyBidAsk.length === 0 ? '' : ( '?search1=' + encodeURIComponent(propertyBidAsk) );
      url += propertyPayment.length === 0 ? '' : ( '?search2=' +  encodeURIComponent(propertyPayment) );
      url += propertyType.length === 0 ? '' : ( '?search3=' + encodeURIComponent(propertyType) );
      url += city.length === 0 ? '' : ( '?search4=' + encodeURIComponent(city) );
      url += min_price.length === 0 ? '' : ( '?search5=' + "=" + encodeURIComponent(min_price) );
      url += max_price.length === 0 ? '' : ( '?search6=' + "=" + encodeURIComponent(max_price) );
      url += min_quadrature.length === 0 ? '' : ( '?search7=' + "=" + encodeURIComponent(min_quadrature) );
      url += max_quadrature.length === 0 ? '' : ( '?search8=' + "=" + encodeURIComponent(max_quadrature) );


  window.location.href = search/addsomethinghere + url;
```

then your web.php

```
Route::get('/search', 'CategoryController@index');

Route::get('/search/addsomethinghere', 'CategoryController@search');
```

then in your controller you can use them as a request.